# pandas dtype output has extra row

Tags: python, pandas

While playing around with pandas I started wondering about the output.

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':[1,2,3], 'col_2':['a','b','c']})
> df.dtypes
  col_1     int64
  col_2    object
  dtype: object
```

The `df.dtypes` call gives three rows.

1. The first row shows that `col_1` has an "integer" type.
2. The second row shows that `col_2` has an "object" type, which is a string.
3. The third row mentions `dtype: object`... but what is this referring to?

Comment: The third row referring to datatype of `df.dtypes` series.

Comment: ahh! cool. feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object returned by `dtypes` is a `pandas.Series` object, by default a `Series` shows it's dtype when printed, it's telling you it is a `Series` od mixed types (since you have `int64` and `object`)

Comment: it shows `object` only even if all the columns are `numeric`.